# Registering base class adapter in Python's sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Considering I have a dynamically created class:

```
def create_dynamic_class(*args):
    class Dynamic:
        def __init__(self, args):
            self.args_string = str(args)
```

How can I register an adapter for `sqlite3` converting this class to an sqlite object such as text?

I have tried creating a base class like so:

```
class BaseDynamic: pass
def create_dynamic_class(*args):
    class Dynamic(BaseDynamic):
        def __init__(self, args):
            self.args_string = str(args)
```

And registring an adapter using [`sqlite3.register_adapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_adapter) like so:

```
import operator
sqlite3.register_adapter(BaseDynamic, operator.attrgetter("args_string"))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How do I register the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the python docs, you may implement a [`__conform__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#letting-your-object-adapt-itself) method on the base class which returns an `sqlite3` object. The method will be inherited by the child class and allow sqlite3 to work with the new dynamic type.

In your case, this is the code you need in order for it to work:

```
class BaseDynamic:
    def __conform__(self, protocol):
        if protocol is sqlite3.PrepareProtocol:
            return self.args_string
```

It will return your string and allow it to exist in the sqlite database.